# wso2 is single logout doesn't sent LogoutRequest to other enrolled SPs

Tags: wso2, logout, saml, opensaml, wso2-identity-server

Scenario: I have 2 SP viz A and B configured in WSO2 IS 5.0 sp1. I have configured Custom Logout URL in B. This logout URL points to the logout for A.
Now when I logout from A, there is no LogoutRequest which is sent from IDP to B.
On the contrary, when I don't configure custom logout URL in B, there is a proper LogoutRequest which is sent to B when I logout from A.

Am I missing out anything over here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cijoy, I checked the scenario you mentioned in WSO2 IS 5.0 SP1 using the travelocity and avis sample apps. The flow seems to be working as expected. Instead of pointing B's logout URL to A could you try making a copy of the B's logout page and point to that. Then when you logout from A the server should send a logout request to B's new logout URL.

Answer (score 0):

> I have configured Custom Logout URL in B. This logout URL points to
>   the logout for A.

Why doing that? The A will receive the logout request twice then. B should expose its logout URL itself. If you do not configure the logout URL, the ACS URL is used to send the logout request.

IMHO: The logout process in the current version assumes the systems / servers are accessible to each other and can communicate between themselves. That's a very strong assumption. Usually (in other identity servers) the SAML single-logout goes though user browser and I assume / expect it will be changed in WSO2 IS as well in future. Some updates are already implemented, but not yet generally available.

Comment: this is helpful. Thanks.The application A is an universal launch application and application B is SAP BO. I'm not sure if I can customize SAP BO to be protected via WSO2 IS. Have you tried WSO2 IS and SAP BO?